# Setting up host for Laravel homestead

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I have some problem setting up the hosts file for my homestead. Every time I run vagrant up or vagrant provision, the new IP configuration that I have added before always get commented.

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
# 192.168.10.10 homestead.test
```

I have to uncomment it every time I start my homestead. Is there any solution for this problem ? Thank you

Comment: Are you using bitdefender?

Comment: Yes, I am using bitdefender antivirus

Comment: This [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1018133/windows-10-hosts-file-entries-been-commented-out) might have the solution for your problem.

Comment: Thanks, your solution works. I didn't know bitdefender is the root problem for it